# How to change font use npm fontfaceobserver?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, timeout, font-family

I use npm fontfaceobserver to select font change for text. But it return error:

```
Error: 3000ms timeout exceeded
    at fontfaceobserver.standalone.js:5:1
```

Here is my code:

```
import FontFaceObserver from "fontfaceobserver";
```

I call it in function:

```
var myFont = new FontFaceObserver(font);
myFont
      .load()
      .then(function () {
        // when font is loaded, use it.
       
      })
      .catch(function (e) {
        console.log(e);
      });
```

File package.json:

```
"fontfaceobserver": "^2.1.0"
```

Fonts array to select:

```
const fonts = [
    { label: "Anton-Regular", value: "Anton" },
    { label: "Archivo-Bold", value: "Archivo-Bold" },
    { label: "Archivo-BoldItalic", value: "archivo_bold_italic" },
    { label: "Archivo-SemiBoldItalic", value: "archivo_semi_bold_italic" },
    { label: "Bangers-Regular", value: "banger_regular" },
    { label: "BarlowCondensed-Bold", value: "barlow_condensed_bold" },
    {
      label: "BarlowCondensed-BoldItalic",
      value: "barlow_condensed_bold_italic"
}]
```

I tried to setup time out = 5000ms or 10000ms but it had still this error time exceeded. What else do I need to fix this?

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't got one already, you need to have a @font-face definition in your CSS.

example from https://fontfaceobserver.com/

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Output Sans;
  src: url(output-sans.woff2) format('woff2'),
       url(output-sans.woff) format('woff');
}
```